# How can I initialize a const member with a pure function?

Tags: kotlin, static-initialization

How can I call a function when defining constants?

I have a complicated mechanism to generate names for an external system and would like to hide that complexity in a function, which I can then reuse in a bunch of places where I need to exchange data with that external service, so that I don't have to remember the details each time.

In Java I could do this:

```java
public class Mcve {
    static final String FOO = magic("friendly name");

    private static String magic(String plain) {
        return plain.replaceAll(" ", "_");
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        System.out.println(FOO);
    }
}
```

This prints "friendly_name", as expected.

How do I do the same in Kotlin?

```kotlin
class Mcve {
    companion object {
        const val FOO = magic("friendly name")  // Const 'val' initializer should be a constant value

        fun magic(name: String): String {
            return name.replace(' ' , '_')
        }
    }
}

fun main() {
    println(Mcve.FOO)
}
```

In Kotlin, the compiler complains that

> Const 'val' initializer should be a constant value

I've tried adding `@JvmStatic` to `magic`, but that did not change the error.

How can I use a (pure) function to initialize a `const`?

Comment: A `const` must be a compile-time constant. The concept of compile-time constants exists in Java as well, but they cannot be *explicitly* declared (in your Java code, `FOO` is *not* a compile-time constant). What's wrong with just doing `val FOO = magic("friendly name")`?

Comment: Thanks @Slaw, that does compile. I was hoping to make it clearer that the value can not change, hence the `const`, but I guess `val` already conveys that.

Comment: Note `const` implies _more_ than read-only. It means the value of the property can be fully evaluated at compile-time, allowing the compiler to inline the value wherever it's used. A function call cannot be evaluated at compile-time, at least not in languages like Kotlin (and Java).

Comment: `val` doesn’t actually convey that on its own. `val` with no custom getter conveys that, which unfortunately is not part of its signature.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the explanations and background, @Slaw and @Tenfour04! If you put that in an answer, I'll gladly accept it.